# If a linear transformation has any two of the properties of being self-adjoint, isometric, or involutory,

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that if a linear transformation has any two of the properties of being self-adjoint, isometric, or involutory, then it has the third. (Recall that an involution is a linear transformation A such that A^2 = 1.)

Comment: For which of these implications do you difficulties to prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self adjoint $A^T=A$, isometric $A^T=A^{-1}$ involutive $A^2=I$.

self adjoint +isometric implies $A^T=A=A^{-1}$ implies $A^2=I$ so $A$ is involutive.

self adjoint +involutive $A^T=A$, $A^2=I$ implies $A=A^{-1}=A^T$ so $A$ is isometric.

isometric+involutive $A^T=A^{-1}, A^2=I$ implies $A^{-1}=A=A^T$ so $A$ is self adjoint.